# seed job asks for script approval in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I was trying to execute a seed job(having github url with groovy scripts) in jenkins and got following error.

> First time build. Skipping changelog.
>   Processing DSL script APIServerDeployer.groovy
>   ERROR: script not yet approved for use
>   Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Could that be related to JobDSL 1.60 introducing [script security](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Script-Security)?

Answer (score 48):

In order to get past this Jenkins security feature, you will need to approve your script.  Go to Manage Jenkins -> In-process Script Approval.  In that screen, you will see the script that you are trying to execute.  There should be an approve button that you'll need to click to approve that script.

[image]

Comment: But how do you do this (approve a script) programmatically?

Comment: I think we all know this..question is how to avoid having to approve all the damn time

Answer (score 29):

Job DSL version 1.60 introduced Script Security; to restore old behavior, uncheck *Enable script security for Job DSL scripts* in the CSRF Protection section of the "Configure Global Security" page. This should only be done if you have another way of approving scripts, such as through git pull request approval if your seed job builds jobs living in git.

Comment: unchecking that option did not have any effect for me (Jenkins 2.107.2).

Comment: Unchecking that option does not seem to remove the list of scripts that are already blocked/pending approval, so you do have to approve the scripts that were already there.  It does prevent new job-dsl changes from having to be approved.

Comment: Unchecking that box did not work for me either (Jenkins 2.198)

Comment: On my Jenkins 2.332.3 system that checkbox appears lower down, not under **CSRF Protection**. I'm guessing that it has no heading.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a groovy script that we use to pre-populate script approvals:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import jenkins.model.Jenkins;
import jenkins.model.*;
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.*;
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.*;

scriptApproval = ScriptApproval.get()
alreadyApproved = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(scriptApproval.getApprovedSignatures()))


// add all manual whitelist methods here.

approveSignature('method groovy.json.JsonBuilder call java.util.List')
approveSignature('method groovy.json.JsonSlurper parseText java.lang.String')
approveSignature('method groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic parseText')
approveSignature('method groovy.lang.Binding getVariables')
approveSignature('method groovy.lang.Binding getVariable java.lang.String')
approveSignature('method groovy.lang.Binding hasVariable java.lang.String')
approveSignature('method groovy.lang.Closure getMaximumNumberOfParameters')
approveSignature('method groovy.lang.GString plus java.lang.String')
approveSignature('method groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object')
approveSignature('method hudson.model.Actionable getAction java.lang.Class')
approveSignature('method hudson.model.Actionable getActions')
approveSignature('method hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause getUpstreamProject')
approveSignature('method hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause getUserId')
approveSignature('method hudson.model.ItemGroup getItem java.lang.String')
approveSignature('method hudson.model.Item getUrl')
approveSignature('method hudson.model.Job getBuildByNumber int')
approveSignature('method hudson.model.Job getLastBuild')
approveSignature('method hudson.model.Job getLastSuccessfulBuild')
approveSignature('method hudson.model.Job isBuilding')
approveSignature('method hudson.model.Run getCauses')
approveSignature('method hudson.model.Run getEnvironment hudson.model.TaskListener')
approveSignature('method hudson.model.Run getParent')
approveSignature('method hudson.model.Run getNumber')
approveSignature('method hudson.model.Run getResult')
approveSignature('method hudson.model.Run getUrl')
approveSignature('method hudson.model.Run getLogFile')
approveSignature('method java.util.Map containsKey java.lang.Object')
approveSignature('method java.util.Map entrySet')
approveSignature('method java.util.Map get java.lang.Object')
approveSignature('method java.util.Map keySet')
approveSignature('method java.util.Map putAll java.util.Map')
approveSignature('method java.util.Map remove java.lang.Object')
approveSignature('method java.util.Map size')
approveSignature('method java.util.Map values')
// ... your list here ...

scriptApproval.save()

void approveSignature(String signature) {
    if (!alreadyApproved.contains(signature)) {
       scriptApproval.approveSignature(signature)
    }
}

// Utility methods
String printArgumentTypes(Object[] args) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object arg : args) {
        b.append(' ');
        b.append(EnumeratingWhitelist.getName(arg));
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

Comment: super useful, thanks! what do you use `printArgumentTypes` for? or did you just forget that there?

Comment: Note that approving `method groovy.lang.GroovyObject invokeMethod java.lang.String java.lang.Object` will allow scripts to do just about anything with only minor cleverness.

You almost certainly don't need to approve that unless the script is doing some very unusual things with dynamic decorators. There's a bug in Jenkins that makes people think that they need that approved, when really they've just typoed a method name.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using the Jenkins Groovy DSL, here's a snippet you can use to approve every script that's pending:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.ScriptApproval

ScriptApproval scriptApproval = ScriptApproval.get()
scriptApproval.pendingScripts.each {
    scriptApproval.approveScript(it.hash)
}
```

See: https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/script-security/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/scripts/ScriptApproval.html

Comment: I tried to use this snippet but ran into some concurrency exceptions. I modified it to get rid of the `each` iteration, which I suspected was involved in the issue, and it worked that way then:
```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.ScriptApproval

ScriptApproval scriptApproval = ScriptApproval.get()
while (scriptApproval.pendingScripts) {
  scriptApproval.approveScript(scriptApproval.pendingScripts[0].hash)
}
```

Comment: Like @mkorvas I too got a **java.util.ConcurrentModificationException**.  However I wanted to check the script content for a particular value _Some text_, and only then approve it. So I did it in 2 loops. The first adding the script hash to an array and 2nd for loop doing the approval.  

`ScriptApproval scriptApproval = ScriptApproval.get()
def hashesToApprove = []
scriptApproval.pendingScripts.each {
 if (it.script.contains("Some text")) {
  hashesToApprove.add(it.hash)
 }
}
for (String hash : hashesToApprove) {
 scriptApproval.approveScript(hash)
}`

Comment: Where can I put this piece of code ? in the end of the seed script file ? I would like to automate this task after each seed trigger

Comment: perfect for me !

Comment: @yarin Yes I put this at the end of a seed file. However you will run into the issue where a Script Approval is not generated until you actually try to run the job generated by your seed. So the first time you run the seed, there is nothing to approve. After if you try to run the job, it will fail because it hasn't been approved. If you then run the seed a 2nd time, it will approve this new script approval (and job can be run). So I'm not sure how you can fully automate this.

Answer (score 8):

Job DSL version 1.60 introduced [Script Security](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Script-Security), which requires you to whitelist scripts.

Read also the hints about [migrating to 1.60](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Migration#migrating-to-160).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to disable it programatically, drop the following script into `$JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d/disable-script-security.groovy`:

```
import javaposse.jobdsl.plugin.GlobalJobDslSecurityConfiguration
import jenkins.model.GlobalConfiguration

// disable Job DSL script approval
GlobalConfiguration.all().get(GlobalJobDslSecurityConfiguration.class).useScriptSecurity=false
GlobalConfiguration.all().get(GlobalJobDslSecurityConfiguration.class).save()
```

Comment: Maybe you don't want the entire setting disabled, but an individual script pre-approved programmatically?

Comment: This did not work for me. I dropped that file and restarted Jenkins but it still required me to do approve the script from the UI.

Comment: Worked for me; @HighwayofLife's suggestion would definitely be preferred, but I'm running in a test sandbox so not necessarily concerned in my use case.

Answer (score 3):

Give a try with disabling script security for Job DSL scripts under Configure Global Security settings.
[Disable script security for Job DSL scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtlVG.png)

Answer (score 1):

**Manage Jenkins** -> **Security** -> disable **Enable script security for Job DSL scripts**

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have enabled groovy sand box below the pipeline

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the concurrent modification exception:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.ScriptApproval

ScriptApproval scriptApproval = ScriptApproval.get()
def items = scriptApproval.pendingScripts;

List<ScriptApproval.PendingScript> arr = new ArrayList<>();
arr.addAll(items);

for (int i= 0; i<arr.size(); i++ )
{
   out.println("Approving... "+arr.get(i).hash)
   scriptApproval.approveScript(arr.get(i).hash)
}
```