# How to approve script snippets from a jenkinsfile via the groovy script console?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my jenkins pipeline file I use the `JsonSlurperClassic` to read build configurations from a .json file. This however introduces code that needs to be approved over the *in-process Script Approval* page. This works fine when I do it over the GUI.

However I also have a script that automatically sets up my jenkins machine which should create a ready-to-work machine that does not require further GUI operations. This script already uses the jenkins script console to approve slave start-up commands. The groovy code that is executed in the script console to do this looks like this.

```java
def language = 'system-command';
def scriptSnippet = 'ssh me@slavemachine java -jar ~/bin/slave.jar';

def scriptApproval = Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList(
    'org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.ScriptApproval')[0];
def scriptHash = scriptApproval.hash(scriptSnippet, language);
scriptApproval.approveScript(scriptHash);
```

This works fine, but now I want to use the same code to approve the script
snippets that come from my pipeline. I exchanged the first two lines with

```java
def language = 'groovy'
def scriptSnippet = 'new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic';
```

where the `scriptSnippet` is taken from the `scriptApproval.xml` file.
Executing this adds a new `<approvedScriptHashes>` entry to the `scriptApproval.xml` file but does not remove the `<pendingSignature>` entry that contains the script snippet. This means it does not work.

My guess is, that the language is wrong, but other values I tried like `groovy-sh` or `system-commands` did not work either. Do you have any ideas why it does not work?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe the `approveClasspathEntry` method? What are you overall trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @mkobit I have a script that sets up my jenkins instance from scratch. I want that my jenkins is ready to go after that script is executed. This means that the script needs to approve all code snippets from my pipeline job, or the pipeline-job will fail on the first run with the request to approve the scripts manually over the GUI.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [`ScriptApproval#approveSignature`](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/script-security/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/scripts/ScriptApproval.html#approveSignature-java.lang.String-) method. Here is an example that works on my Jenkins 2.85

```
def signature = 'new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic'
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.ScriptApproval.get().approveSignature(signature)
```

Comment: And how do I automatically approve the ScriptApproval#approveSignature method?

Comment: Use this plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/permissive-script-security/

Answer (score 7):

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.*
toApprove = ScriptApproval.get().getPendingScripts().collect()
toApprove.each {pending -> ScriptApproval.get().approveScript(pending.getHash())}
```

Comment: I have not tried if this works, but it seems more convenient then the other solution to approve the scripts without having to know their exact signatures.

Comment: However, you don't know what those are until you run the script... It will fail as many times it runs...

Comment: I get a `Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.ScriptApproval$PendingScript`

Comment: You can mix the Permissive Script Security plugin and this solution, and you shouldn't have problems with any approval anymore. At least I am testing this solution and it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I thought if anyone else is looking for answers then this could help. If you already have a list of known signatures for script approvals and if you would like to do all of the approvals at once, then the snippet mentioned in the below link works well.

[Here's a groovy script to pre-populate script approvals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55714171/2367302)